# putting lambda function in clicked signal

Tags: python, lambda, pyqt, pyside

I was looking at this code example and I can't understand how this lambda function works in this scenario.

```
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class ButtonDel(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QModelIndex)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if (
            isinstance(self.parent(), QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView)
            and self.parent().model() is index.model()
        ):
            self.parent().openPersistentEditor(index)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent)
        button.clicked.connect(lambda *args, ix=index: self.clicked.emit(ix))
        return button

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        editor.setText(index.data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole))

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(0, 2)
    for i in range(10):
        it1 = QtGui.QStandardItem()
        it1.setData(QtCore.Qt.Checked, QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole)
        it1.setFlags(it1.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
        it2 = QtGui.QStandardItem()
        it2.setData("text-{}".format(i), QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
        model.appendRow([it1, it2])

    # pass the view as parent
    delegate = ButtonDel(w)
    w.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, delegate)

    def on_clicked(index):
        print(index.data())

    delegate.clicked.connect(on_clicked)

    w.setModel(model)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I understand that lambda functions with any number of arguments can be written like this.

ex (lambda *args: sum(args))(1,2,3) = sum((1,2,3)) = 6

What does *args do? Since we don't have any arguments like above '(1,2,3)' what is its use here.

```
button.clicked.connect(lambda *args, ix=index: self.clicked.emit(ix))
```

if index is getting passed into this slot here:

```
def on_clicked(index):
        print(index.data())
```

I tried to rewrite this lambda function as a regular function but it doesn't seem to have the same functionality. What would be the regular function implementation of it?

Comment: Can you post in your question the version you wrote that doesn’t use a lambda function and highlight the differences in the functionality that you referred to?

Comment: Who tells you don't have any arguments? The [`clicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) signal has one and quite clear argument, which is the `checked` state of the QAbstractButton. The fact that you're using a standard QPushButton (which is not checkable by default, and therefore will always have `False` as the `clicked` signal argument), is irrelevant, unless its *`checked`* property value is set to `True`, either programmatically, or through the `setCheckable(True)` function, assuming it's been pressed.

Comment: Also note that you should be *extremely* careful in keeping references to QModelIndex instances, as they are normally discarded as soon as possible. If your model changes (possibly by removing/inserting/moving a row equal or below the current index row), that index will be invalidated, resulting in unexpected results.